# Matlab Sample Frequency of Points

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using the function frestimate to find the frequency response of some blocks in my model. It seems that the code works fine, but i get the following warning.

Warning: In "sysest = frestimate(modelname,op,io,in)", the linearization I/O point(s) io(2) are located
at continuous or fixed in minor time step Simulink signal(s) and the linearization I/O point(s) io(1) are
located at discrete sample time Simulink signal(s) with sample time 0.004. The sample time of the
estimation result, "sysest.Ts", is being set to 0.004, however, there might some channels in this
frequency response data that are continuous. To stop this warning, make sure all the linearization input
and output I/O points have identical sample time or divide them into groups such that each I/O point
group has identical sample time and run a separate FRESTIMATE command with each group.

I totally have no idea how i should fix it. i always take care of sampling frequency. I am using Runge-Kutta solver with fixed step of 0.004 (Fs = 250) and the input to my fretimate function is also defined like this:

```
input = frest.createFixedTsSinestream(0.004,{1 100});
```

my input port is output of a "constant" block (io(1)) and my output port (io(2)) is the output of an add block. Any idea? I have no idea about the clue which this warning gives.

here is a snapshot of my model, if it helps.

may be it is not that clear, but my input and output are at last input and output of magenta block. it returns all my operating points to zero while it is not true.

[image]

---

When i run this code:

```
op = findop(SimFile,15)
```

i get the following result.

(1.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn1
      x: -3.31e-19
      x: 2.46e-05
(2.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn2
      x: -4.25e-19
      x: 7.39e-05
(3.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn3
      x: -7.2e-21
      x: 3.63e-07
(4.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn4
      x: 0
      x: 0
(5.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn5
      x: -4.72e-19
      x: 1.62e-05
(6.) Cortex/Transfer Fcn6
      x: 3.02e-18
      x: 0.0002

while at 15, the output of all my transfer functions has none zero values. where could be the problme?

Answer (score 0):

Display the sample times in your model, as detailed in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html), and make sure your linearization points are on signals which have the same sample time (at the moment, it looks like they're not). Use [Rate Transition](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/ratetransition.html) blocks if necessary to enforce the correct sample time(s) throughout your model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can i then convert between discrete to continious? i am using ZOH, but it doesnt change anything

Comment: You can't, unless the discrete signal goes through a continuous block.

Comment: so, which block do you suggest? like transfer function with gain = 1?

Comment: You're thinking about it the wrong way round. Use rate transition blocks to convert your continuous signals to discrete signals (or specify a discrete sample time in the constant block for example), and then all your linearization points will be on discrete signals. It's difficult to say any more without seeing the model and the different signals/sample times.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. It is going to really make me crazy! it even returns the operating points completely wrong (i compare it with what i see on the scopes). I will do your suggestion and let you know. But i have now idea why these things are happening

Comment: The transfer function blocks you are using are continuous. Use a rate transition on the output of these to convert to the correct sample, or use a discrete transfer function. You can also specify the (same) discrete sample time for the gain and look-up table blocks you use.

Comment: I didt it and my results now totally changed. what is happening? whats is the difference? which one is correct? my previuos data or this one?